# Progress Bar when running function inside foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, progress-bar

I have a foreach loop that calls a function to set values to an array.  Sometimes it takes hours to complete depending on how many times it has to run thru the function to complete.

What I would like to have is a progress bar or at least a 1/1000 completed type progress indicator.

Is this possible?  If so how could I implement this into my code?  Would it be in the function or in the foreach loop?  Been researching and found some examples using for and $i++ but I am not really sure how to implement that since I am already using a foreach loop.

Thanks much.

```
 function scrape_amazon($links) {
 //my code runs here to set all values in $ret array.
 }


 foreach($links as $link) {
$ret = scrape_amazon($link);
 }
```

Comment: Neither, PHP can't do this at all. You'll need Ajax and JavaScript, and a complete restructuring probably. Unless you want an ugly continual flush, and that's definitely not a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into ajax progress bars and see what I can learn.  Hopefully I will not have to restructure anything...

Comment: hours! you expect a person to sit and watch? why not run it in the background, and let them know when it's done.

Comment: That is what I do now but I would like to be able to periodically check on it to see where it is at in the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP probably isn't really the right tool for this task, however what you could do is:

- Launch the slow code as a background process, and output progress to a file.
- Have a PHP script that polls that file for progress information (either by page refresh or AJAX)

Launching the background process can be done in several ways, including:

- Launch via cron every 60 seconds, and poll for new jobs spooled in some readable area
- Launch via a fork/exec mechanism from a web page
- Launch as a daemon at system startup

It will take some effort to avoid problems with multiple executions and/or overlap.

Comment: I created a table in mysql and updated it on each loop.  Then I used Ajax to read a php file that polls the table every 5 seconds.  Works great! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I use this, which well, not an ajax, do only flushing, but not so ugly.

I place an image

```
<img src='progress.gif' height=18 width=0 name=probar>
```

Then set on every event done on server a `echo` a line, then `flush`:

```
echo "<script language='JavaScript'>\ndocument.probar.width=".(($sys["probar_width"]/$task_all)*$task_i).";\n</script>\n";
flush();
```

If your server (eg. apache) use caching (eg. gzip is enabled) it won't work well.